# shouldn't model.trainable=False freeze weights under the model?

Tags: keras, keras-2

I am trying to freeze the free trained VGG16's layers ('conv_base' below) and add new layers on top of them for feature extracting.
I expect to get same prediction results from 'conv_base' before(ret1) / after(ret2) fit of model but it is not.
Is this wrong way to check weight freezing?

## loading VGG16 and set to untrainable

```
conv_base  = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=[150, 150, 3]) 
conv_base.trainable = False
```

## result before model fit

```
ret1 = conv_base.predict(np.ones([1, 150, 150, 3]))
```

## add layers on top of the VGG16 and compile a model

```
model = models.Sequential()
model .add(conv_base)
model .add(layers.Flatten())
model .add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model .add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
m.compile('rmsprop', 'binary_crossentropy', ['accuracy'])
```

## fit the model

```
m.fit_generator(train_generator, 100, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=50)
```

## result after model fit

```
ret2 = conv_base.predict(np.ones([1, 150, 150, 3]))
```

## hope this is True but it is not.

```
np.equal(ret1, ret2)
```

Comment: Have you tried freezing all the layers? `for l in conv_base.layers: l.trainable=False`

Comment: If it doesn't work, maybe you need to set it as trainable after adding it to the sequential model...

Comment: @DanielMöller yes, that one works perfectly. but i don't get this why model.trainable works differently against the "layer.trainable for layer in model.layers".

Answer (score 12):

This is an interesting case. Why something like this happen is caused by the following thing:

**You cannot freeze a whole model after compilation and it's not freezed if it's not compiled**

If you set a flag `model.trainable=False` then while compiling `keras` sets all layers to be not trainable. If you set this flag after compilation - then it will not affect your model at all. The same - if you set this flag before compiling and then you'll reuse a part of a model for compiling another one - it will not affect your reused layers. So `model.trainable=False` works only when you'll apply it in a following order:

```
# model definition
model.trainable = False
model.compile()
```

In any other scenario it wouldn't work as expected.

Answer (score 10):

You must freeze layers individually (before compilation):

```
for l in conv_base.layers: 
    l.trainable=False
```

And if this doesn't work, you should probably use the new sequential model to freeze the layers.

If you have models in models you should do this recursively:

```
def freezeLayer(layer):
    layer.trainable = False
    if hasattr(layer, 'layers'):
        for l in layer.layers:
            freezeLayer(l)

freezeLayer(model)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `model.trainable=False` won't work, instead `for layer in model.layers: layer.trainable=False` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The top-rated answer does not work. As suggested by Keras official documentation (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/), it should be performed per layer. Although there is a parameter "trainable" for a model, it is probably not implemented yet. The safest way is to do as follows:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile()
```