# What is the difference between setting a Keras model trainable vs making each layer trainable

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, backpropagation

I have a Keras Sequential model consisting of some Dense Layers. I set the trainable property of the whole model to False. But I see that the individual layers have still their trainable property set to True. Do I need to individually set the layers' trainable property also to False? Then what is the meaning of setting trainable property to False on the whole model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shouldn't model.trainable=False freeze weights under the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204116/shouldnt-model-trainable-false-freeze-weights-under-the-model)

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer this question explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

To be able to answer this you need to take a look at the source code of Keras, which you might be surprised after doing so because you would realize that:

- The `Sequential` class [is a subclass](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c658993cf596fbd39cf800873bc457e69cfb0cdb/keras/engine/sequential.py#L24) of `Model` class, and
- the `Model` class [is a subclass](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c658993cf596fbd39cf800873bc457e69cfb0cdb/keras/engine/training.py#L36) of `Network` class, and
- the `Network` class [is a subclass](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c658993cf596fbd39cf800873bc457e69cfb0cdb/keras/engine/network.py#L35) of `Layer` class!

As I said, this might be a bit surprising that a Keras model is derived from a Keras layer. But if you think further, you would find it reasonable since they have a lot of common functionalities (e.g. both get some inputs, do some computations on them, produce some output, and update their internal weights/parameters). One of their common attributes is `trainable` attribute. Now when you set the `trainable` property of a **model** as `False` it would **skip** the weight update step. In other words, it does not check the `trainable` attribute of its underlying layers; rather, first it **checks its own** `trainable` attribute (more precisely in `Network` class) and if it is `False` the updates are skipped. Therefore, that does not mean its underlying layers have their `trainable` attribute set to `False` as well. And there is a good reason for not doing that: a single instance of a layer could be used in multiple models. For example, consider the following two models which have a shared layer:

```
inp = Input(shape=...)

shared_layer = Dense(...)
sout = shared_layer(inp)

m1_out = Dense(...)(sout)
m2_out = Dense(...)(sout)

model1 = Model(inp, m1_out)
model2 = Model(inp, m2_out)
```

Now if we set `model1.trainable = False`, this would freezes the whole `model1` (i.e. training `model1` does not update the weights of its underlying layers including `shared_layer`); however, the `shared_layer` and the `model2` **are still trainable** (i.e. training `model2` would update the weights of all its layers including `shared_layer`). On the other hand, if we set `model1.layers[1].trainable = False`, then the `shared_layer` is freezed and therefore its weights would not be updated when training either `model1` or `model2`. This way you could have much more control and flexibility, and therefore you can build more complex architectures (e.g. GANs).

Comment: So I came across a code snippet where the author first sets all the `layers.trainable = False` and then the `model.trainable=False` and then calls `model.compile`. Now if I want to reuse the layers whose weights have been frozen (as done above), then I can just call `layers.trainable=True` again and reuse the layers, right ?

Btw thanks for the above answer, cleared my initial confusion.

Comment: @HarshitTrehan If by "reuse" you mean you want to make the weights of the layer trainable again, then you are right: you first set the `trainable` to `True` and then compile the model (i.e. call the `compile` method) to make this change effective (otherwise, the trainability status of the layer would NOT change without compiling the model).